# Arbitrary precision type

Tags: c#

Is there such a type\implementation in C#?

It is needed to calculate figures up to 10<sup>10,000</sup> magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

Your question body suggests you need to hold numbers that are arbitrarily *large*, and for that question, then yes, there are various **Big Integer** libraries available (I believe .NET 4 includes one in the Framework).

However, your question title refers to 'precision', which suggests you want to hold an arbitrary number of figures to the *right* of the decimal point - and for that, you'd need either a Rational class (combined with a Big Integer) if you were only dealing with rationals, or a clever symbolic manipulator (such as for example Mathematica has) if you were going to be leaving the rationals.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new BigInt class in Fx4: System.Numerical.BigInteger

But no floating point type as far as I'm aware of.

Comment: The thing is I need Floating point one. (i need both 10e10000 as well as 10e-10000)

Edit: Atm im using Visual Studio 2005 with framework 3.0.
I've found J# library - ill try using it.